# adobe livecycle Message box displayed separately not in a single box

Tags: javascript, adobe, dialog, livecycle-designer

I am using Adobe Livecycle ES2. My code is fine but all my validations are being displayed as a list in one single message box and that's not what I want. I want them to display after the user leave each field that's being validated. I tried solution like File>Form Properties> Form Validation but I don't have the Form validation option. I am wondering if I can get it to work by javascript coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can add field-specific JavaScript code to the exit event for each field. If the user enters a value that doesn't pass the validation, you can then script something (a messagebox, an alert popup or some text) to appear as the user tries to leave the field.

You may want to use softer coded validation (which warns the user that the field isn't correctly completed but still allows them to move elsewhere in the form) in the exit event and use harder/stricter validation at the end of the form, for example, before the form is submitted) so that the user can't submit the form without completing the necessary fields but they can still progress with later fields even if the earlier fields aren't complete.